# .ado file from manual not executed although code is correct

Tags: stata

I tried to create an `.ado` file by myself following the steps listed in http://www.stata.com/manuals13/u18.pdf pp. 38.

So I had a file named `hello.ado` listed in `c:\ado\personal\`. `which hello` successfully finds the file.

The content of the file is

```
program hello
        display "hi there"
end
```

When I type `hello` in the Stata terminal, I get

```
unexpected end of file
(error occurred while loading hello.ado)
r(612);
```

Why's that? I use Stata 13.1 in an office network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a text editor other than the Stata built-in, insert a blank line at the end with the keyboard "enter" key.
In those cases where there is no blank line, Stata may not find the end-of-line character and complain.

When using the built-in editor, after saving the file to disk, Stata will insert the line for you (Stata 13.1 for MS Windows). You can see this is the case because the last line is enumerated as in the image.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. But either blank line or `exit`, the [Stata manual](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/u18.pdf) is wrong.

Comment: I think the very small issue here is that you must have EOL characters to mark an end of line at the end of **every** line in your program file, including the last. Stata works across platforms, so  whichever of carriage return and line feed is native to your operating system is needed. I know you specify Windows, but I am spelling that out generally for people on other systems.

Comment: That is: You don't need `exit`; you don't need an extra blank line.

Comment: The "blank line solution" is only meant as a medium to guarantee the existence of the EOL character in the last line. That is why I suggested to type in "enter"/"return", therefore creating a blank line. I think this will work on all major platforms, if not all, but I may be wrong of course.